# 'DataSource' property cannot be set declaratively

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, drop-down-menu

I have the following code that is throwing this error but the solutions I've found say, "Have you tried the DataSourceID instead of DataSource?" with no indication as to what should be used for the DataSourceID value.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="id" SortExpression="id" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="dgCells"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="first_name" SortExpression="first_name" HeaderText="First" ItemStyle-CssClass="dgCells"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="last_name" SortExpression="last_name" HeaderText="Last" ItemStyle-CssClass="dgCells"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="login_pw" HeaderText="Password" ItemStyle-CssClass="dgCells"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Race">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "race_name") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlRaces" DataValueField="race_id" DataTextField="race_name" >>>DataSourceID=""<<< />
        </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:EditCommandColumn EditText="Edit" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Ok"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
</Columns>
```

What I should be inserting into the DataSourceID="" value?

Comment: You should use the GridView instead of the DataGrid if possible

Comment: Is the GridView that much different or easier to use? This is .NET 4.0 that I am trying to use in WDE2010 if that matters at all.

Comment: The GridView was introduces in .NET 2.0, GridView vs Datagrid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataSourceID` should be set to the ID of a control on your page that inherits from  `DatasourceControl` such as `SqlDatasource` if you want to populate the grid from an SQL database

To bind the DropDown in a GridView

```
protected void GV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {  
    var ddl = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlRaces");
    ddl.Datasource = GetRaces();
    ddl.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess I still don't understand. What I need is for a dropdownlist to appear in edit mode for that row with the items in the list to show the values from the lu_races table. The grid shows all the data I have bound to it, but do I need a separate datasource for the dropdownlist?

Comment: You should bind the DropDown using it's DataSource property in the GridView's OnRowDatabound event.

Comment: @Magnus - In this case, it might be cleaner to set ddl.DataSource in ddl's DataBinding event and to just call .DataBind() in Page_Load.

Answer (score 4):

`DataSourceID` would be the id of a datasource element on your page like `ObjectDataSource` or `SqlDataSource`.

The `DataSource` property is used when binding to a collection of objects from codebehind.

Comment: Yes, I accidentally used DataSource instead of DataSourceID.

Answer (score 1):

For quick and dirty applications you could use da DataSourceControl directly on your aspx page. Then you can set the `DataSourceId` Property of your data bound control to this control. For larger applications it is not advisable to use this technique, because you have no separation between your user interface and your business or data access code.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceMode="DataReader"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, LastName, Title FROM Employees">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView
    id="GridView1"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
</asp:GridView>
```

A better way would be to use an object data source where you can access any .net class in your libraries.

```
<asp:ObjectDatasource
    id="ObjectDataSource1"
    runat="server"
    selectmethod="GetAllEmployees"
    typename="Samples.AspNet.EmployeeLogic" />
```

And the third option is to use the `DataSource` property which is mainly set in the Page_Load event of the code behind class.

Comment: Okay, this method does appear worth trying, but would Magnus' suggestion be the right way to do it since your label of "quick & dirty" implies that it's more of a rudimentary approach for example's sake?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But your question was about the DataSourceId and not about how to bind a  DropDownList. Sorry I didn't realize that.